# What are the JQuery plugins that turn <select> drop downs into fancier ones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

I can only find this one... http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

I looked all over the internet.

Comment: Please define "fancier". What results are you looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/).

From their website:

> Uniform masks your standard form controls with custom themed controls. It works in sync with your real form elements to ensure accessibility and compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Gentle Select](http://shawnchin.github.com/jquery-gentleSelect/). It is configurable to do multiple columns and rows, etc....

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Tutorialzine, they have some great tutorials. I found this one on select elements: http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/better-select-jquery-css3/

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out: [jQuery UI Selectmenu: An ARIA-Accessible Plugin for Styling a Custom HTML Select Element](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/). It's by the Filament Group, the people behind jQuery UI. It'll even work with your existing jQuery UI theme!